# Getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in flutter/Android, even though the certificate is installed on the device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I have an android application developed in flutter and connected to my backend with a web API which is deployed on IIS. The API is only allowed over secured connection (client’s policy), so I created a self-signed certificate and root CA with `openssl`, installed on the server, imported to IIS and added it to the website binding, and also installed it on the mobile device which is listed in “Trusted Credentials > User”.

This is how I created the certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 356 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=MY CN/C=MC/L=MY L/O=MY O"  -keyout rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt

openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

-- uses the csr.conf
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf

-- uses cert.conf
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile cert.conf

-- create pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -out myPFX.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

This is the content of the csr.conf:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = MC
ST = MY ST
L = MY L
O = MY O
OU = MY OU
CN = MY CN

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = example.com (my website address)
IP.1 = 10.10.10.10 (my IP address)
```

And this is the content of cert.conf:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com (my website address)
```

If I do not install the root certificate on the mobile, I cannot open the website (I get the error “your connection is not private…”). But after installing the root certificate, I can open a browser (Chrome) and view my API/Website (which are the same application) without any issue. However, when I try to call the API from my application, I get this error:

```
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: I/flutter (21014): CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

I know in flutter we can by-pass the certificate validation by overriding `createHttpClient` method (which is not recommended for production):

```
@override
HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
  return super.createHttpClient(context)
    ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
}
```

but I am wondering, why does the website open the same URL without error (the certificate is accepted, and connection is considered secure) but the request from the mobile application to the same URL fails?!
Is there any way to make the mobile application recognize the self-signed certificate?

PS: I don’t have much knowledge about the certificates…